# How positioning wil work in css?

Tags: css, css-position

https://jsfiddle.net/z3fhtbq9/

I expect the above fiddle will show the background color red from top to bottom of the body.But it doesn't.Why?

```
<div style="background-color:red;position:relative;top:0px;bottom:0px;">
```

Comment: ....minimal example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z3fhtbq9/11/    https://jsfiddle.net/z3fhtbq9/9/ Check the two fiddles.Why is is not showing background in first fiddle

Comment: Hello, how are you?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : What are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div size (height width)..it will work

```
<div style="height: 100vh;background-color:red;position:relative;top:0px;bottom:0px;">
</div>
```

The div had height 0 and <s>width 0</s>(width was same always) thats why no change was observed. If you had added something inside the div like some text or simply gave a height-width it could have worked.

Here 100vh means the element will always be 100% height of the viewport a device has.

> An element with absolute positioning is not affected by other elements
>   and it doesn't affect other elements. So basically it is not affected
>   by any other element. So the 100% vh doesn't work on it. It will work
>   if you put in a relatively positioned div of full size.The absolutely
>   positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned
>   ancestor(non static).

Comment: The `width` was 100%, only nothing had any `height`.

Comment: @deceze.: yes exactly..ok let me edit answer...Just answered hurriedly.

Comment: actually what is the use of giving position:relative top:0 bottom:0 in here?It should automatically extend right?

Comment: yes @KarthikeyanSoundararaj..:) sorry for late reply.

Comment: That's ok @coderredoc.But why it is not extending in here?

Comment: Yes..In my example

Comment: @KarthikeyanSoundararaj.: Its not about your code...the div element you create that way always have 0 height unless you modify height or put any thing inside that div.

Comment: In the above fiddle i didn't mention the height.How it is showing the background color in whole area?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSoundararaj.: The 100vh part which I explained in answer.

Comment: I'm asking why the same is not working with relative positioning?The updated fiddle is also having absolute positioning.It won't also work with relative

Comment: @KarthikeyanSoundararaj.: check the answer.

Comment: So if i add some more element, will it get overlap?

Comment: ah if it abosolute then it will be out of flow..otherwise yes..it willo overlap.yes https://jsfiddle.net/dk1hme11/1/ @KarthikeyanSoundararaj

Answer (score 0):

I don't see relation to positioning, but to fill the body with this div, you need to set the width and height of the elements. You can set on css:

```
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0;}
```

and on your div style you add width and height 100%, like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red;position:relative;top:0px;bottom:0px;"></div>
```

Or you can just put the red background style on the body div.

Comment: positioning a element as relative is "relative to itself".Means if a element is positioned as relative with top 50px, then  it will get place 50px from top where it will normally place.If this is true, in my case i'm giving position relative, top and bottom position to 0.So it has fill the whole body.But it is not happening.Why?

Comment: Check the following fiddle    https://jsfiddle.net/z3fhtbq9/9/  How it is showing the background color in whole area?